# Get users yahoo email

Tags: oauth, yahoo-api

I think this yahoo email of users is little problem with yahoo and twitter.

I have searched many days for this but no luck.

Im getting user details like that

```
  print( $profile->location) ;   --------got location
  print( $profile->gender) ;   --------- got gender
```

But when i want to get the email i couldnt .

Have tried this

```
  print( $profile->emails->handle) ;
```

But i got this error

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in mywebsite/index.php on line 103
```

Have tried this

```
 print( $profile->emails['handle']) ; -----no luck
```

I have seen [this](http://developer.yahoo.com/forum/OAuth-General-Discussion-YDN-SDKs/How-to-get-Yahoo-Id-with-Oauth/1320206452634-0520691e-74dc-4baf-8868-e137cb7d0d8e) but it seems there are many emails .

How can i get the main email ?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

i have tryed this

```
  foreach($profile->emails as $k){
      echo 'handle: ' . $k->handle . '       -----> i got error here 'Undefined property: stdClass::$handle'
            id: ' . $k->id . '               -----> i got the id (no error)
            type: ' . $k->type . '<br>';     -----> i got the type (no error)
  }
```

i dont know why handle returns error always . is something wrong with handle ?

**EDIT2:**

i have made this:

```
  var_dump($profile);
```

and it gives this

```
 object(stdClass)#14 (20) 
 { ["uri"]=> string(70) 
  "http://social.yahooapis.com/v1/user/1JKK3SDVWE6QDPAQRVUFRN7NDU/profile" 
  ["guid"]=> string(26) "1J4K3SDVSW6QDPQQRVU1RN7NDO"
  ["birthYear"]=> int(1977) 
  ["birthdate"]=> string(3) "12/8" 
  ["created"]=> string(20) "2006-10-08T10:32:21Z" 
  ["displayAge"]=> int(37) 
  ["emails"]=> array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#22 (3) { ["id"]=> int(3)
                                                          ["primary"]=> bool(true)
                                                        ["type"]=> string(4) "HOME"} }
  ["familyName"]=> string(0) "" 
  ["gender"]=> string(1) "M" 
  ["givenName"]=> string(0) "" 
  ["image"]=> object(stdClass)#23 (4) { ["height"]=> int(192) 
                                        ["imageUrl"]=> string(55) "http://l.yimg.com/dh/ap/social/profile/profile_U197.png" 
                                        ["size"]=> string(7) "192x192" 
                                        ["width"]=> int(192) } 
  ["lang"]=> string(5) "en-UK" 
  ["location"]=> string(31) "NA, Indisponible ENGLAND 16548" 
  ["memberSince"]=> string(20) "2003-05-10T21:34:41Z" 
  ["nickname"]=> string(5) "diFirst" 
  ["profileUrl"]=> string(51) "http://profile.yahoo.com/1J4K3SDVSE6ADPQQRVJFRN7ND1" ["searchable"]=> bool(true) 
  ["timeZone"]=> string(12) "Europe/ENGLAND" 
  ["updated"]=> string(20) "2012-09-21T14:35:30Z" 
  ["isConnected"]=> bool(false) 
  }
```

Comment: Could you show the result of `var_dump($profile);`?

Comment: i have edited , and added EDIT2.

Comment: it seems that handle doesnt exist in emails array!!!